# How to convert (m*2) list elements into comlex form(x+iy) in python

Tags: python, list, 2d

How to convert (m*2) list elements into complex form(x+iy) in python.

Comment: Show us the code, please?

Comment: [ 362.2  383. ]
 [ 363.   382.2]
 [ 363.2  382. ]]
[[ 361.   382.8]
 [ 360.   382.8]
 [ 359.   382.8]
 ..., 
 [ 361.8  381. ]
 [ 361.8  382. ]
 [ 361.   382.8]]
[[  48.2  243. ]
 [  48.2  242. ]
 [  48.2  241. ]
 [  48.   240.8]
 [  47.2  240. ]
 [  47.2  239. ]
 [  47.2  238. ]
 [  47.   237.8]
 [  46.2  237. ]
 [  46.2  236. ]
 [  46.2  235. ]
 [  46.   234.8]
 [  45.2  234. ]
 [  45.2  233. ]
 [  45.2  232. ]
 [  45.   231.8]
 [  44.2  231. ]
 [  44.2  230. ]
 [  44.2  229. ]....this is the list

Comment: i want to find complex form (x+iy) for this list which of dimension(m*2)

Comment: I understand. But did you write any code? What have you tried and what's the issue you faced?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that:

```
m=[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
comp=[l[0] + l[1] * 1j for l in m]
```

Then `comp` is

```
[(1+2j), (3+4j), (5+6j)]
```

And you can also perform algebraic operations as usual. For example, `comp[0]+comp[1]` gives you `(4+6j)`.

Comment: thank you Miriam.......implementation was succesful....thn alot

Comment: As for my case, above method converted list into complex form but it has taken different numbers to convert into complex form. For example, 
 
[ 362.2 383. ] [ 363. 382.2]

Comment: [ 362.2 383. ] [ 363. 382.2]

Comment: As given in list, i want complex form as (362.2+383.0*j), but above method (results in 362.2+363.0*j), which is not desirable.....So what be appropiate changes i should do....

Comment: as list is long enough, so how to put comma between them....??? Also,why this is not working, is this not a list???

Comment: This: [ 362.2 383. ] [ 363. 382.2] is indeed not a list. You can read here about the structure of lists in python: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html, and here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html  (and in many other places) how to parse strings like that and turn them into a list.

Comment: I couldn't edit my previous comment, so I modified it here:                       Just set m=[ [ 362.2, 383. ], [ 363., 382.2] ] and the code above will give you the result: [(362.2+383.0*j),(363+382.2*j)]